# Is there an inline web page compiler?

Tags: templates, web, proxy

I'd like some sort of web proxy which on seeing:

```
<html>
<title>foo!</title>
<inline page="http://something.else/foo"/>
</html>
```

Fetches http://something.else/foo which contains:

```
hello world!
```

And injects it in the response:

```
<html>
<title>foo!</title>
hello world!
</html>
```

Obviously, bespoking something like this would be a doddle, but I'm curious if there's anything similar already out there.

I'm sure there's something out there, but I've not got the first idea what terms to search for...

Comment: Natively in HTML that is not possible, even though people have discussed [HTML imports](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/) as a possibility. You might want to use a server side language like PHP, or a client side solution like JS to load contents dynamically.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping for a piece of code to cobble stuff together at the server side before sending it to a client. Yes, I could bespoke something in PHP, I was wondering if that could be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with SSI in Apache or Nginx with "virtual" includes.

(Though I was hoping for something more meaty)